# How to get the count of the jobs running using kubectl command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am able to get the jobs under the namespace using kubectl command:

```
kubectl get jobs --namespace xxx
```

This is giving me the jobs information

[image]

I would like to print the count of jobs using kubectl command. How to do that?

Comment: did any of the answers help you? If yes can you accept the most appropriate answer? If not, can you provide more info why none of the answers helped you? Accepting and upvoting help the folks to keep answering@Ayushi

Answer (score 2):

`go-template` way, no pipes or installation needed. Just good old kubectl:

```
kubectl get jobs --namespace xxx -o go-template='{{printf "%d\n" (len  .items)}}'
```

`len` is an inbuild function in `go-template` to return the number of elements to its argument. Eg: `items`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are want to get number of job that are running in namespace you can get it using like this also

`kubectl get jobs -n dcs | grep -v NAME | wc -l`

Comment: wc and grep will not be valid as I have windows environment .

Comment: try this in git bash terminal it will work

Comment: no need to use `grep -v NAME`, just use `--no-headers`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the, **wc** or **jq** for this

```
kubectl get jobs --output name | wc -l
```

with **jq** :

```
kubectl get jobs --output json | jq -j '.items | length'
```

Comment: wc will not be valid as I have windows environment .

Comment: Read more at : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install

Comment: you can use `jq` with windows maybe, https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/

Comment: you can use the powershell  `| Measure-Object -line` or else you can install the official Linux command line in windows also WSL.